# MS OneNote screen capture stopped working

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

With MS OneNote installed, I could use the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> key-combo to launch the screen capture utility. But it all of a sudden stopped working. According to [this post](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.onenote/windows-s-screen-clip-not-working/137814), that "sometimes happens" and can be turned back on by toggling the checkbox lableled "Place onenote notification icon in the taskbar" (under File -> Options -> Display, if using OneNote 2010).
Unfortunately this trick didn't work for me. (I.e., it didn't turn on the Notification icon in the tray).

I tried to turn it on manually in the Customize section of the Tray, selecting "Show icon and notifications" on the MS OneNote Quick Launcher, but was told "This icon is not active and will not be visible until it becomes active"

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "Place OneNote icon in the notification area..." checkbox is selected, you should find a **OneNote Screen Clipper and Launcher** shortcut in your Startup folder. Just click that to manually activate the taskbar icon.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a response to an old thread, but since I've experienced this frustrating issue off and on for a while and have been unable to find an answer (until I figured it out literally 30 seconds ago) I figured I'd post the solution that worked for me.

In my case, it was pure user error...  and may be for others too!

I'm using a gaming keyboard... that has a switch to disable the Windows key while in games...  and it was switched to disable the Windows key!  Duh!

I'm happy to report that Windows + S now works flawlessly.  So my point is, make sure your Windows key isn't disabled either by hardware or software.

Hope this helps others!

By the way, this is a Windows 7 machine, and I know that this will not resolve issues on Windows 8 or 8.1, as the functionality has been modified in those OS's.

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to SuperUser! Come back soon, and keep contributing!

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue and the fix was to close onenote.exe via Taskmanager.  There were two instances.  Then using the shortcut mentioned above in the startup folder to relaunch it.  Shortcut then worked again for me.

Comment: I haven't tried your suggestion, but I appreciate you posting it. Thanks, and welcome to SuperUser! Come back soon, and keep contributing!

Comment: For me an app i was writing was capturing keystrokes and prohibiting this.  So, the usual thing, close other apps, reboot the PC.

Answer (score 0):

The short cut is no longer Win + S but instead Win + Shift + S

[Why doesn't the screen clipping tool work anymore?](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Why-doesn-t-the-screen-clipping-tool-work-anymore-311c21ff-68d9-4e2a-8769-ede9faafdb1/)